# Joomla 3 cannot click on submenu

Tags: javascript, php, css, joomla

Hello I am new to stack oferflow, and relatively new to code too. The thing is I have this Joomla site that uses Mikon template.

The main menu has some submenus. The problem is it seems they are not clickable form de home page, just form the article pages.

Try to click an element of the submenu under "Servicios" parent here: 
http://mryc.mx/

Then try to click an element of the sumbenu under "Servicios" parent here: 
http://mryc.mx/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=33

I have been searching for the reason, maybe it has something to do with the template, anyone has ever encountered something like this?

This is the main menu code:

```
<div id="sp-main-menu" class="visible-desktop pull-right">
    <ul class="sp-menu level-0">
      <li class="menu-item first home"><a href="http://mryc.mx/#sp-slider-wrapper" class="menu-item first home"><span class="menu"><span class="menu-title">Inicio</span></span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu-item"><a href="/index.php#sp-about-wrapper" class="menu-item"><span class="menu"><span class="menu-title">Nosotros</span></span></a></li>
      <li class="menu-item parent">
          <a href="/index.php#sp-service-wrapper" class="menu-item parent ">
             <span class="menu">
                  <span class="menu-title">Servicios</span>
             </span>
          </a>
          <div class="sp-submenu sub-level" style="top: 80px; left: 0px;">
          <div class="sp-submenu-wrap" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">
             <div class="sp-submenu-inner clearfix" style="width: 200px;">
               <div class="megacol col1 first" style="width: 200px;">
                 <ul class="sp-menu level-1">
                   <li class="menu-item first active"><a href="http://mryc.mx/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=32&amp;amp;Itemid=176" class="menu-item first"><span class="menu"><span class="menu-title">Banca de inversión</span></span></a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="/index.php/2013-11-07-05-29-34/inteligencia-financiera" class="menu-item"><span class="menu"><span class="menu-title">Inteligencia Financiera</span></span></a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="/index.php/2013-11-07-05-29-34/asesoria-de-negocio" class="menu-item"><span class="menu"><span class="menu-title">Asesoría de Negocio</span></span></a></li>
                    <li class="menu-item last"><a href="/index.php/2013-11-07-05-29-34/asesoria-para-instituciones-financieras" class="menu-item last"><span class="menu"><span class="menu-title">Asesoría para Instituciones Financieras</span></span></a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </li>
       <li class="menu-item last"><a href="/index.php#sp-bottom-wrapper" class="menu-item last"><span class="menu"><span class="menu-title">Contáctanos</span></span></a></li>
      </ul>    
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Update:

I just found out that if you right click on the not worling link and select "Open in new page /tag" the link works fine. Also I tested in Firefox and the error persists so we can rule out browsers.

Comment: Add some code in question...

Comment: The submenu item are well clickable if I visit them, maybe you just want to display some background change when you are hovering the items.

Comment: Well they seem clickable but the thing is that when you click them they dont open any article. Or con you access the articles form the submenu being in the main page? Thank you very much for the quick response

Comment: Rayon Dabre I just added the conde

Comment: I think that the slider is causing some conflict. The menu without the slider works, the one with the slider don't.

Comment: Exactly that is the case. The thing is that I can´t find where the conflict might be, any ideas?

Comment: @Franco about the slider, I unpublished it from joomla administrator and tested again. The links didn't work without the slider. I am starting to think that it has something to do with how Joomla is resolving the URLs. But still I don't have a clue...

Answer (score 0):

The link on that submenu item (`/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=32&Itemid=176`) doesn't work, but if you change it to something using a valid anchor tag like `/index.php#sp-bottom-wrapper` (the same as the Contact link) it does work.  So it looks like the Services link itself works because it's going to `#sp-service-wrapper`:

```
<section id="sp-service-wrapper" class=" ">...</section>
```

which has a valid ID.  Taking it a step further, if you update the submenu items to link to anchor tags of the individual sections then those links should work too.  BUT, the 4 sections (Investment Banking, Financial Intelligence, Business Advisory, and Advisory for Financial Institutions) don't all have specific IDs, so it's not possible right now.  For instance, this is what one of those sections looks like:

```
<div class="st-fancy-icon-boxes st-fancy-icon-boxes-style1 center ">
    <div class="box-icon clearfix"><i class="st-box-icon fa fa-money"></i></div>
    <div class="box-title clearfix"><h4><font><font class="">Investment Banking</font></font></h4></div>
    <div class="box-desc clearfix"><font><font>The adequacy of resources is a cornerstone for growth and sustainability of any business. </font><font>Through our investment banking services, we support our customers with the necessary resources for new projects, expansions, caps and together continue their road to success.</font></font></div>
    <div class="box-readmore clearfix"><a href="http://mryc.mx/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=32"><font><font>See more...</font></font></a></div>
</div>
```

So you'll need to somehow change the HTML for that first line to add something like `id="banca-de-inversion"`, THEN you can update the submenu item to link to `/index.php#banca-de-inversion` and it should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your resoponse.

The problem is not entirely that, the thing is that the submenus should point to different pages, not elements with specific ids inside the page.

For example: 
Investment Banking submenu item should point to: 
http://mryc.mx/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=32&amp;Itemid=176
As you can see it is a separate page of the website. There is a section in the home page for "Investment Banking" but I dont want to point to that one in the submenu. Hope I was clear and thank you again!! :)